# DL_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't work

Tags: c, windows, mingw, shared-libraries

I madeC programs named drive.c and mylib.c.

drive.c is main module mylib.c is sub modulle that I want work as shared library .

I can compile them with this step on MINGW

```
gcc –fPIC –g –c –Wall mylib.c 

gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libmylib.so.1 -o /c/opt/lib/libmylib.so.1.0.1 mylib.o -lc

gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic  -I./ -L/c/opt/lib -o drive.exe drive.c –l:libmylib.so.1
```

Finally I did `drive.exe`

Then Windows Dialog Message was shown `program can start because libmylib.so.1.0.1 is missing`.

LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set.

```
$ set|grep LD
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/c/opt/lib

$
```

And there is libmylib.so.1.0.1

```
$ ls -la /c/opt/lib
total 98
drwxr-xr-x 2 JAC484 Administrators  4096 Mar 18 14:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 JAC484 Administrators  4096 Mar 14 15:47 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 JAC484 Administrators 45356 Mar 18 14:23 libmylib.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 JAC484 Administrators 45356 Mar 18 14:23 libmylib.so.1.0.1
```

If I copied `libmylib.so.1.0.1` in same directory of `drive.exe`,`drive.exe` can run.

How Can I tell the system where libmylib.so.1.0.1 is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows doesn't use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  Your shared library DLL will need to be in the same directory as `drive.exe` or in a directory in the `PATH`.

The full details of Windows' DLL search is documented here:

- [MSDN: Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx)

Comment: I think I can use LD_LIBRARY_PATH on MINGW can't I.